# Which version of web3 is more current, 1.0.0-beta2 or 1.0.0-beta.29

Tags: web3js

I just ran `npm outdated` on my project and it shows

```
Package       Current       Wanted         Latest
web3    1.0.0-beta.29  1.0.0-beta2  1.0.0-beta.29
```

However `web3` has a rather dreadful history with respect to version naming and so forth.

Running `npm view web3 versions` gives a long list ending in

```
[...
'1.0.0-beta.28',
'1.0.0-beta.29',
'1.0.0-beta1',
'1.0.0-beta2' ]
```

But if I go to the `1.0` branch in Github, [`package.json`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/1.0/package.json) shows the version as `1.0.0-beta.29`

Is `1.0.0-beta2` truly more recent than `1.0.0-beta.29`?

Answer (score 1):

The 1.0.0-beta2 name has been an issue for a while now. As late as mid-December.

https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/966#issuecomment-350527286

beta.29 is the latest version.